# While incoming call is ongoing between two users and other incoming call is received, then the another incoming call should be declined automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, linphone, linphone-sdk

I am facing an issue in which user is on first incoming call and then receives an other incoming call. Then I tried to disconnect the call by giving the reason busy by using the Linphone method. But this method declines my both calls the one which I received and the other one which is incoming. Can anyone suggest that how can I disconnect the single call. Because SDK deoes not provide me any callback or state for disconnecting particular one call.

```
if (linphone_core_get_calls_nb(LC) > 1)
{
linphone_call_decline(call, LinphoneReasonBusy);
return;
}
```

Any help would be kindly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the max_calls property to 1 in your linphonerc, under the [sip] section, and all incoming calls after the first one will be denied with Busy reason automatically.